# Server serving old SSL certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate, godaddy

About 20 days ago, we have renewed our SSL certificate for https://www.pscquestion.in from GoDaddy. But we are still getting old certificate. But GoDaddy says it is installed properly. We have tested a certificate in sslshopper.com, digicert.com, godaddy.com and ssllabs.com. The results are not stable. sometimes we are getting a valid certificate, but most of the time we are getting an old certificate.

Anyone can give some suggestions to fix this.

Comment: How exactly did you install this certificate? Into what server software?

Comment: Godaddy team installed the certificate.

Comment: What server did they install it on? Why did they do it and not you?

Comment: I think they using apache. i can see that they installed new certificate. issue is we receiving old certificate also (some times). We tested this with different machine, different browser and different network also. Also SSL testing sites also giving different results, some times certificate will be valid, sometimes it shows old invalid certificate.

Comment: They might have some load balancing setup, and some of their load balanced servers don't have the updated certificate. You need to push GoDaddy to fix the issue. Provide them detailed descriptions how they can see the issue.

Comment: That sounds like shared web hosting. We can't support that here; you'll have to follow up with GoDaddy.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved. The issue is with Godaddy. As per support team, they restarted some handler and now it is working well. Thanks for the support.